# Angular2 rxjs call to rest api and get undefined output

Tags: rest, angular

I have problem with my Angular2 service. My function call to rest server, next I would like to print output but `console.log` shows `undefined`.

Main class

```
export class EventListComponent implements OnInit {
  events: Event[];

  constructor(
    private eventService: EventService
  ) {}

  loadPosts() {
    console.log('loading');
    this.eventService.getEvents()
      .subscribe(
        events => this.events = events,
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    console.log(this.events); // undefined
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Load comments
    this.loadPosts();
  }
}
```

And EventService

```
@Injectable()
export class EventService {

  private eventsUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/search';

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getEvents(): Observable<Event[]> {

    return this.http.get(this.eventsUrl)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }

}
```

Whats is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're logging `this.events` before it is set. Do:

```
  loadPosts() {

    this.eventService.getEvents()
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
      .subscribe(
        events => {
          this.events = events; 
          console.log(this.events);
      });
  }
```